# How to plot markers on the edge of an axis without showing the data outside the axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a plot that shows only part of my data. But when a marker is on the edge of the axis I want to see the whole marker. It seems that both conditions are irreconcilable. Using `clip_on=False` :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import ion, plot, xlim, ylim
ion()
a = np.arange(11)
plot(a,'.', markersize=10, clip_on=False)
xlim(1,9)
ylim(1,9)
```

results in:

[image: whole marker but datapoints outside axis]

Here the whole marker on the edge is visible, but the datapoints outside the axis also.

Using `clip_on=True` (default) results in:

[image: quarter marker but no data outside axis]

Here the edge markers are only partly visible, but there are no data points outside the axis.

Is there a way in matplotlib to reconcile both requirements, without modifying the data?

Comment: What do you classify as modifying the data? You could apply a mask to your data in your call to `plot` and still use `clip_on=False`

Answer (score 0):

is it ok to modify the scale? . if so this can accommodate

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import ion, plot, xlim, ylim
ion()
a = np.arange(11)
print(a)
plot(a,'.', markersize=10, clip_on=True)
xlim(0,10)
ylim(0,10)
```

Comment: @FrankTap  i just changed xlim,ylim so that all data points will fall with in the markers.

Comment: xlim and ylim are intentionally the way they are. I only want to show part of the data and the whole marker on the edge of the axis.